# How to detect number of objects from image?

Tags: c#, image, image-processing, emgucv

I have a windows forms application and i want to count number of objects from a medical images. For instance

[image]

I used an algorithm which can take the contours of every object from the image.

```
private void findContoursToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Image<Gray, byte> imgOutput = imgInput.Convert<Gray, byte>().ThresholdBinary(new Gray(100), new Gray(255));
        Emgu.CV.Util.VectorOfVectorOfPoint contours = new Emgu.CV.Util.VectorOfVectorOfPoint();
        Mat hier = new Mat();

        Image<Gray, byte> imgout = new Image<Gray, byte>(imgInput.Width, imgInput.Height, new Gray(100));

        CvInvoke.FindContours(imgOutput, contours, hier, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.RetrType.External, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.ChainApproxMethod.ChainApproxSimple);
        CvInvoke.DrawContours(imgout, contours, -1, new MCvScalar(123, 0, 0));

        pictureBox2.Image = imgout.Bitmap;

    }
```

But I can't find out the number of cells from the image. Any advice or algorithm I have to use  ?

I search within `EMGU` documentation but I don't find any function which does somethink like I want.

Any advice or answer will be rewarded.

**If you consider that is too broad, I don't want the implemented algorithm. I just need some ideas or a suggestion of algorithm i have to use.**

Comment: Didn´t you post the exact same question some hourss before? I guess it was deleted, as it´s far too broad.

Comment: @HimBromBeere, I don't want the  implemented algorithm. I just need some ideas or a suggestion of algorithm i have to use. That's not too broad I think.

Comment: There are a million and one potential solutions to this question, but most of those solutions will not work. Therefore one needs to do a lot of work to find a good answer to this question. Therefore it is too broad.

Comment: And how didn´t http://www.emgu.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=2964 help you?

Comment: @HimBromBeere, `HNext` isn't a property of Contour. So the link you provided doesn't help me

Comment: Sure it is as of the docs: http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/1.5.0.0/Help/html/9bee392d-b500-773f-aa59-41e3ffe4d663.htm

Comment: @HimBromBeere, 1.5 is the lowest version. Now it's egmu 3.0. But i cannot find the equivalent of the `HNext`. Have you idea what's is the equivalent of `HNext` in egmu version 3 ?

Comment: Unclear and too broad. What cells do you refer to. The bigger browns or the smaller greens?

Comment: @Silencer, the bigger.

Comment: I think using the global threshold is not a good choice. Because the bigger cells borders are not that clean. [This is one of the best separations after global threshold, but still not good](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G0dYX.jpg).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably a bit basic and brute force, but how about selecting a random point on the image that is close to the green colour, then effectively search for 'matching' colours (with a tolerance for the same colour.  As you visit each pixel, colour it black so you don't look at it again and count how many pixels you have coloured in.   Each time you select a pixel, make sure it's not black.  Once you can't find any more points, if the number of black pixels is greater than a tolerance (so you only find 'big' polygons), then count it in the number of cells.